# Migrating a MediatorLiveData to SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have a MediatorLiveData that uses three LiveData sources. When any of them emits a new value and I have at least one of each, I use the three values to produce the output for the UI.

Two of the sources are user settings for how to sort and filter a list, and the third is the list data, pulled from a Room database Flow.

It looks something like this:

```
val thingsLiveData: LiveData<List<Thing>> = object: MediatorLiveData<List<Thing>>() {
    var isSettingA: Boolean = true
    var settingB: MySortingEnum = MySortingEnum.Alphabetical
    var data: List<Thing>? = null
    init {
        addSource(myRepo.thingsFlow.asLiveData()) {
            data = it
            dataToValue()
        }
        addSource(settingALiveData) {
            isSettingA= it
            dataToValue()
        }
        addSource(settingBLiveData) {
            settingB= it
            dataToValue()
        }
    }
    private fun dataToValue() {
        data?.let { data ->
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val uiList = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    produceUiList(data, isSettingA, settingB)
                }
                value = listItems
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a clean way to convert this to a SharedFlow, preferably without any `@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi`. The only SharedFlow builder function I've come across is `callbackFlow`, which isn't applicable. Are you intended to use `flow { ... }.asSharedFlow(...)` in most cases, and if so, what would that look like here?

The two settings LiveData I also plan to migrate to flows.

Comment: i think you can use [combine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) function as a replacement for MediatorLiveData

Comment: @IR42 Does it matter if the sources are hot SharedFlows vs. cold Flows when using `combine`? I'm not clear on what behavior to expect when working with hot flows, since most documentation on functions seems to still be written with the assumption that Flows are always cold.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think this answer strongly relates to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645981/1495230

Comment: @Deinlandel Yes, kind of. That's my own answer. I understand it better than I did when I wrote this. Cold flows with hot flow sources simply miss the emissions that arrive before they are collected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The source Flows can be combined using [`combine()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html), which creates a cold Flow that, when collected, will start collecting from its source Flows, which may be hot or cold.

I was originally thinking that I must be missing something and that there should be some way to directly combine hot Flows into a combined hot Flow. But I realized it makes sense that the operators should only return cold Flows and leave it up to you to convert it back to a hot Flow if that's what you need.

In many cases, such as mine, it's perfectly fine to leave it cold. I only collect this Flow from one place in my UI, so it doesn't matter that it only starts combining the sources when it's collected. The source hot Flows don't care whether something is currently collecting them or not...they just keep emitting regardless.

If I collected this Flow from multiple places or multiple times, then it might make sense to use `shareIn` on the combined Flow to make it hot, which would avoid redundant work of combining the sources. The potential downside would be that it would combine those sources even when nothing is collecting, which would be wasted work.

```
val thingsFlow: Flow<List<Thing>> = combine(
    myRepo.thingsFlow,
    settingALiveData.asFlow(),
    settingBLiveData.asFlow()
) { data, isSettingA, settingB -> produceUiList(data, isSettingA, settingB) }

// where produceUiList is now a suspend function that wraps 
// blocking code using withContext
```